# The form of solutions of $p*k-q*j=r,$ for $(p,q)=1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I would like to find the form of solutions of $p*k-q*j=r,$ for $(p,q)=1$ for any fixed $r < pq$ and $k,j \in \mathbb{N}$. I tried to look at the divisibility of $p=cq+b.$ But I didn't have any success.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the form"? A closed form doesn't exist. Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) for more information.

Comment: Given any one solution $k=k_0$, $j=j_0$ the general solution in integers is $k=k_0+jt$, $j=j_0+kt$, $t$ any integer.

Answer (score 1):

As provided by vrugtehagel`s comment, there are no closed forms, and more information can be seen in the link he provided.

However, here is one solution that is always guaranteed to be true.

Since you merely have to find $k$ to solve this equation, you just have to find $k$ such that $pk \equiv r \pmod q$. You use [Euler`s Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), and set $k$ to $p^{\phi(q)-1}r$, where $\phi$ is the [totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). Since you have set that $\gcd (p,q)$ must be equal to $1$, this implies that $pk \equiv r \pmod q$. From that you have to calculate $\phi(q)-1$ and and $j$. Well, $\phi (n)$ is not easily calculated, but it seems the closest thing to a form of a solution.

So therefore, you are guaranteed to find integers solutions if $j \equiv p^{\phi(q)-1}r$.